# How do you use the Dungeon Defender's Portal Gun?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

The topic pretty much sums up my question. I have not yet figured out how the gun operates aside from the fact that it creates Portal portals. The weapon description indicates that it deals 250+ base damage, but how is that damage applied to the monsters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gun itself is actually not able to shoot, unless you use the skill "[Piercing Shot](http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Piercing_Shot)". This is where the damage modifier comes in to play, as it increases the damage done by the "Piercing Shot" skill. As far as I know, that is the only usage of the damage modifier displayed, when using the Portal Gun.

Comment: yes, piercing shot + portal gun is an awesome combination.  If you upgrade it a few times, you can easily hit 10k damage with your piercing shot.

Comment: Well that certainly is disappointing news. Not exactly all too useful for a huntress for soloing.

Comment: @Sorean  That is right, but the portal gun is extremely effective in multiplayer.  Sending enemies walking back and forth in front of a wizard's towers, for instance, or unleashing piercing shot in tight spots can make the difference between winning and losing.  Also, as a last resort, you can dump a whole lot of enemies straight into the abyss/lava but you do lose the mana/items they drop.

Comment: I never thought about dropping them into lava/abyss. Thanks for the tip, it would make some of insane soloing easier.